# Modify template for auto-creating class fields in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

In Android Studio, the default template for auto-creating a field seems to be:

```
private final Type field;
```

If you do the following in a constructor:

```
this.newField = arg1;
```

and if newField is not a member of the class, then auto-resolving the error in Android Studio (cmd+1, or ctrl+1 on most keymaps), will provide the option to auto create the field.

However, as mentioned the default template is:

```
private final Type field;
```

How can I change this in Android Studio? In my specfic case, I am wanting to remove the final from the template, as I do not always specify final fields in my classes, and would rather make that design decision myself then let Android.